# Views grouping rows case-sensitive, I need to ignore case

Tags: views

I have a view which groups rows in a table according to the first letter of the title. Some of the letters are uppercase and some are lowercase. View treats the upper and lower case as separate groupings (see image attached) but I want them to be grouped case-insensitively.

I've checked my db tables are ci and I've tried to alter the query using `hook_views_query_alter` but haven't managed to find a solution yet.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The query executed is corrected, when adding a count value on the grouping (for example when adding a glossary), you will get a count with merged grouping (case-insensitive).

The problem here is when adding a `Grouping field` with `Use rendered output to group rows` enabled, it will do the grouping with case-sensitive because a `B` is not equal to `b`. To resolve the problem, you can implement `YOURMODULE_views_pre_render()`, and clone the institution name to a new datamember and transform this to uppercase. To notify the view that the grouping field should use the new created datamember, you can change its alias.

Here is some sample code

```
function YOURMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view)
{
    // only execute code on 'your_view_name'
    if ($view->name !== 'your_view_name') {
        return;
    }

    // 'title_grouping' is the field used to regroup the nodes
    // 'node_title_upper' is the new datamember that will be added to node object
    $view->field['title_grouping']->field_alias = 'node_title_upper';

    // loop through each node, and assign an uppercased node title to the 'node_title_upper' datamember
    foreach ($view->result as $result) {
        $result->node_title_upper = strtoupper($result->node_title);
    }
}
```

Comment: nice answer....

Comment: @mike Vranckx could you please explain how should I use a newly created property (node_title_upper) in my view?

Comment: You can't use the created property within inside your view settings. This property is only used internally to change the behavior of the sorting.

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 8, this can be done pretty effortless thanks to Twig.
Just override the output of the grouping field with its value plus Twig's built-in uppercase filter (`|upper` or `|capitalize`), see screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Quick and easier way.

If you are using views PHP field, Then convert required field to uppercase using strtoupper() function right there.

Then group views result by this converted PHP field.

Comment: You should avoid enabling the PHP Filter module as it has security implications.